# Italic text into a tooltip using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

How may I transform some text to italic using the tooltip of bootstrap ?

This is a snippet code..

In my exemple I want to transform the text "title" to italic !

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul>
     <li><a href="#"> msg1</a>
     </li>
     <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="this is a <i> title </i>">
         <a href="#">msg2</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use `data-html="true"` in the tooltip markup.

http://www.codeply.com/go/tjkGpE9vAJ

Comment: It's probably best to use [StackOverflow's built in code snippet tools](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) as opposed to relying on external sites that may break or go down as time passes.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `data-html="true"` to your li tag as such:

```
<li data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="this is a <i> title </i>">
         <a href="#">msg2</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the text to *Italic* you can simply do this in your CSS:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

This is the class to target the text in the bootstrap tooltip, make sure to include your custom CSS **AFTER** the bootstrap CSS

---

**EDIT**

This opens up a lot more possibilities in styling your tooltip

Hope this helps!